# How to run Scuba project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, javacard, sourceforge

I try to use Scuba project.I downloaded source with SVN checkout and imported it into Eclipse .Also i imported scuba_smartcards project. Everything is perfect but i have one problem.When i try to run scuba project like java application,have this error message:

```
Selection does not contains main type
```

I don't know is a correct to run this source like java application or not.By the way i created my own java class and i want to use scuba's source in main method
Ho i can solve my problem? 
thanks everyone
P.s i also found source in github

> https://github.com/credentials/scuba

I'm using scuba_sc_j2se

Answer (score 1):

SCUBA is a framework, basically it is a library with active components. Libraries are not standalone applications so they will not contain a `main` method of their own. You cannot just run it, you need to write or copy an application that *uses* the framework through the API presented by SCUBA.

One of these applications is the [jMRTD application](http://www.jmrtd.org/) from which SCUBA originated.

Comment: Thanks your attention .where or how i can find application that uses the SCUBA's framework? @Maarten Bodewes

Comment: Possibly searching the internet - although using a particular library is hardly a *feature* so programs may not explicitly list it. Obviously jMRTD uses SCUBA as Martijn split it off from jMRTD.

Comment: did you mean this application ? ( http://www.jmrtd.org/) ? @Maarten Bodewes

Comment: Yes, I did mean that application